# AeroGlass Window Effect does not instantly apply and shows as unblurred for a split second

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

When I open my window, my window doesn't instantly get blurred, it gets blurred after a splitsecond but before that I can see the window transparent with the opaque background color.

One culprit I am guessing is because of the minimize animation that I tried replicating in a window where WindowStyle is set to none, it's the function called SetAnimation.

Is there a way to fix this or it's just like that natively? I'd appreciate the help thanks!

```
<Window x:Class="AcrylicBlurDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Hello Blur!" Height="500" Width="500"
        Background="#01000000"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center">
            Win32 <LineBreak/>
            Acrylic Blur
        </TextBlock>
            <Label Foreground="White">Opacity:</Label>
            <Slider Value="{Binding BlurOpacity}" Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Interval="15" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="15" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Margin="2,0,-2,0"></Slider>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


    internal enum AccentState
    {
        ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND = 4,
        ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 5
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct AccentPolicy
    {
        public AccentState AccentState;
        public uint AccentFlags;
        public uint GradientColor;
        public uint AnimationId;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
    {
        public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
        public IntPtr Data;
        public int SizeOfData;
    }
    
    internal enum WindowCompositionAttribute
    {
        // ...
        WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
        // ...
    }
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);
    
        private uint _blurOpacity;
        public double BlurOpacity
        {
            get { return _blurOpacity; }
            set { _blurOpacity = (uint)value; EnableBlur(); }
        }
    
        private uint _blurBackgroundColor = 0x990000; /* BGR color format */
    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EnableBlur();
        }
    
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern long GetWindowLongPtrW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern long SetWindowLongPtrW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
   
    
        public enum WindowStyles : uint
        {
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = 0x00CF0000,
            WS_POPUP = 0x80000000,
            WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000,
            WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000,
            WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000,
            WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000,
            WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000
        }
    
        [Flags]
        public enum StyleFlag : uint
        {
            windowed = WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WindowStyles.WS_THICKFRAME | WindowStyles.WS_CAPTION | WindowStyles.WS_SYSMENU | WindowStyles.WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
            acrylic = WindowStyles.WS_POPUP | WindowStyles.WS_THICKFRAME | WindowStyles.WS_CAPTION | WindowStyles.WS_SYSMENU | WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WindowStyles.WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        }

    public void SetAnimation(IntPtr handle)
    {
        SetWindowLongPtrW(handle, -16, (long)StyleFlag.acrylic);
        SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0020 | 0x0002 | 0x0001); // SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE
        ShowWindow(handle, 5);

    }
    
        internal void EnableBlur()
        {
            var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    
            var accent = new AccentPolicy();
            accent.AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND;
            accent.GradientColor = (_blurOpacity << 24) | (_blurBackgroundColor & 0xFFFFFF);
    
            var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);
    
            var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);
    
            var data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData();
            data.Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
            data.SizeOfData = accentStructSize;
            data.Data = accentPtr;
            
            SetWindowCompositionAttribute(windowHelper.Handle, ref data);
    
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
        }
    
        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            EnableBlur();
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks incorrect. Multiple methods of the same signature cannot coexist in a class. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Oops my bad, I fixed it now